# How get and display a product custom field from WooCommerce order items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I am working on an invoice system for my woocommerce shop.

I am using a plugin that adds weight unit custom field to all products(simple and for each variable of variant product)

I had managed to add the quantity unit column to the invoice plugin, and for simple products, I manage to fetch the field.

On the other hand, this method is not working for fetching the unit of a variant in a variable product.

The following code is what I use to get the custom field.

Please help

```
/**
     * Adds line item quantity to columns data array.
     *
     * @param array  $data    line item data.
     * @param int    $item_id item ID.
     * @param object $item    item object.
     */
    public function add_quantity_column_data( &$data, $item_id, $item ) {
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        $quantity_suffix = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_upw_quantity_suffix', true);
        $quantity_suffix_sep = " ";
        $data['quantity'] = $item['qty'] . $quantity_suffix_sep . $quantity_suffix
        
    }
```

the custom field key is  `_upw_quantity_suffix`.

Answer (score 4):

To handle product variations custom field too, you can try this revisited code version:

```
/**
 * Adds line item quantity to columns data array.
 *
 * @param array  $data    line item data.
 * @param int    $item_id item ID.
 * @param object $item    WC_Order_Item_Product Object.
 */
public function add_quantity_column_data( &$data, $item_id, $item ) {
    $product    = $item->get_product();
    $qty_suffix = $product->get_meta( '_upw_quantity_suffix' );
    $sepatator  = ' ';

    if ( ! empty($qty_suffix) ) {
        $data['quantity'] = $item['qty'] . $sepatator . $qty_suffix;
    }
}
```

It should work.

Or you can also try:

```
/**
 * Adds line item quantity to columns data array.
 *
 * @param array  $data    line item data.
 * @param int    $item_id item ID.
 * @param object $item    WC_Order_Item_Product Object.
 */
public function add_quantity_column_data( &$data, $item_id, $item ) {
    $product    = $item->get_product();
    $qty_suffix = $product->get_meta( '_upw_quantity_suffix' );

    if ( empty($qty_suffix) ) {
        $product    = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );
        $qty_suffix = $product->get_meta( '_upw_quantity_suffix' );
    }
    $sepatator  = ' ';

    if ( ! empty($qty_suffix) ) {
        $data['quantity'] = $item['qty'] . $sepatator . $qty_suffix;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! your first appliance had worked